# About how large is a clean install of OS X?

Tags: disk-space, install

If you were to wipe a hard drive clean and install OS X Mountain Lion, with one user account and no user data files. (so simply OS files) How large, in disk space, would OS X (how much hard drive space would be used on that unused system?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Install OS X Mountain Lion.app` I have is about 4 GB, but the uncompressed size shown by Pacifist is about 9 GB. My initial snapshot of a 10.8 VM was about 11 GB, but about 1 GB was taken up by `/var/vm/swapfile`.

If you have a laptop with 4 GiB of RAM, `/var/vm/sleepimage` will take up about 4 GiB after you put the laptop to sleep once.